# Ignoring zero in DateTime.ParseExact with IT-it culture

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm parsing this date: `"3/1/1961"` with the following code:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(theStringDate, "d", lang.Culture);
```

I think everybody will agree with me that `"3/1/1961"` and `"03/01/1961"` are the same date. However, in the first case the code will crash and in the second it will not.

Why is C# behaving this way? Is there any way `"3/1/1961"` should not get interpreted correctly? How can I tell the compiler to ignore the absence of `0` before the number?

Forcing my user to write `0` before every number or using JS to force the presence of a `0` are both unacceptable solutions. What can I do?

---

> What is the value of lang.Culture?

When the problem arised, I was testing from an italian browser so, I guess, it is "IT-it".

Comment: What is the value of `lang.Culture`?

Comment: it depends on the user. I was testing from an italian browser when the problem arised.

Comment: The clue is in the word exact.

Comment: To expand upon Tony's comment:  For `ParseExact` to work, the input would have to match _exactly_ `new DateTime(1961,1,3).ToString("d", lang.Culture)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using parse exact and the input string isn't in the format you specify. C# is not behaving weird, you're just misusing the method. This snippet is directly from msdn and exactly explains why you get an exception;

```
       // Parse date-only value without leading zero in month using "d" format.
  // Should throw a FormatException because standard short date pattern of  
  // invariant culture requires two-digit month.
  dateString = "6/15/2008";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

There are several solutions available to you. Here are few off the top of my head; change your format specifier (I think replacing `"d"` with `"g"` will solve your problem in this case, you'll still get exceptions for other formats though), change `DateTime.ParseExact` to `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`, or change your input so it's in the *exact* format you require.

Personally I'd recommend getting rid of `ParseExact`. Do you know exactly what format your date is going to be in? It seems like you don't. If you don't, why would you be using `ParseExact`?

Comment: TryParse saved the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure how you are parsing with the current format `d`, it should be `"d/M/yyyy"`

```
string theStringDate = "03/01/1961";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(theStringDate, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The format `"d/M/yyyy"` works for both single digit and double digits day/month.

Comment: I'm guessing OP doesn't want to use the invariant culture, given that it's got `lang.Culture` in the call. Is there a solution which doesn't depend on the invariant culture?

Comment: I suggest replace the `/` in the format string with `lang.Culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator`  and we can use the `lang.Culture`

Comment: what if the user is connected with ENG culture? "d/M/yyyy" wont work anymore.